# Creating a unique string value from keyword and using it for Input Text keyword

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to create a unique string by embedding epoch time stamp after a static string as:

```
*** Keywords ***
Unique Title
    [Return]  ${title}   
    ${secs}=  Get Time  epoch   
    ${time}=  Convert To String     ${secs}
    {title}=  Catenate  SEPRATOR=-  Title   ${time}

*** Test Cases ***
Test_Enter_Unique_Text
    Open Browser    @{urlUnderTest}
    Input Text  name=alertTitle   Unique Title
```

Its not working I am not able to get the return value of Unique Title keyword, in the input box text is getting entered as "Unique Title". 
Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the keyword and save what it returns, then use the saved value in the test case:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test_Enter_Unique_Test
    ${title}=  Unique Title
    ...
    Input Text    name=alertTitle    ${title}
```

Comment: Bryan your suggestions Worked!